# How to find vertices that have at least one single-direction links in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to find each vertex that has a one-way connection to at least one other vertex. This is what I have, but it is clearly wrong.

```
g.V().has("label","SomeVertex").as('Vertex').Out().where(__.in().hasNot('Vertex'))
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
g.V().as('a').
  where(out().not(where(out().as('a'))))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/8m

Comment: Hopefully a good query planner would generate the same result but you can also write the query without the first where.
g.V().as('a').out().not(where(out().as('a')))